# Magento Products are not showing in Shop

Tags: php, magento, import, product

Hope you can help me today. I imported about 85.000 Products from an SQL Source via Magmi. These Products are showing in the backend, they are "active", I updated the index (all of them), deleted the cache, made sure, that the products are in any category, made sure all mandatory fields are filled out, and they have a price. The products are not in Stock, but when I manually add a product thats not in stock, it is shown in the shop. And if i modify an imported product and increase the amount I have in stock, they are still not shown.

The products are all visible in catalog and in search, but I just cant find then clicking on the category in the menu. But if I search for a specific product I can find it.

Got anybody an idea?

Cheers

EDIT: Here I got a picture from Magmi import Process
[image]

And i only have one store, and one store view, that has default values

Comment: Please post the code you've written, it's usually not possible to answer a question without seeing your code.

Comment: @NIklas Have you assigned correct website and store during import process.

Comment: Where can I see which product has which website assigned?

Answer (score 1):

Following things you can check -

- Check **Visibility** of the product.
- Check if the product is **assigned to a category**.
- Check if the product is **assigned to a store view**.
- Check if the product is **In Stock**.
- Check if the product has a **qty assigned**.

Comment: The product is visible, it is in stock,1 qty, it is assigne to a storeview and to a category. Nothing visible. I can only search for articles.